# How to shrink to printable area in C#?

Tags: c#, printing

Greetings,

I have problems (when trying to print from c# to certain printers that do not have large print areas. Is there a way to shrink to printable area (like Adobe Acrobat do)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the size of your image, then the size of the printing area (from the printer settings and margins - as mentioned in the other post) and then calculate a ratio for shrinking horizontally or vertically (whichever is higher, so the image is not cropped). Use this ratio in a scale transform on the printer graphics context before drawing there the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use for printing? Most likely you will have to query the printer for it's margins and then adjust the drawing code to print inside the printable area.

In other words - you would have to do it "by hand".

Answer (score 0):

In .Net, you should be using the classes in the `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace to print.  When you do that, you call the `Print()` method from a `PrintDocument` object.  That will cause the `PrintDocument`'s `PrintPage` event to be raised.  The `Graphics` property of that event's `PrintPageEventArg` argument has a `ClipBounds` property.  Use this property to check printable area.